# Call attribute window with ArcObjects C#

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I want to programatically call `AttributeWindow` using C# ARCGIS SDK.

```
UID uidDockWin = new UIDClass();
uidDockWin.Value = "esriEditor.CreateFeatureDockWin";
dockWindow = ArcMap.DockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(uidDockWin);
dockWindow.Show();
```

above code works well and call CreateFeatures Window. I tried following for AttributeWindow,

```
uidDockWin.Value = "esriEditor.AttributeWindow"; AND
uidDockWin.Value = "{44276914-98C1-11D1-8464-0000F875B9C6}";
```

however my program crashes when i click on Toolbar Add-in button where above code executes in `OnClick` method.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve results in the following way:

```
UID uidDockWin = new UID();
uidDockWin.Value = "esriEditor.AttributeWindow";
ESRI.ArcGIS.Editor.AttributeWindow attWin = editor.FindExtension(uidDockWin) as AttributeWindow;
attWin.Visible = true;
```